# Does Miniconda also benefit from MKL optimization for numpy?

Tags: numpy, anaconda, intel-mkl, miniconda

For scientific computing use cases, it is amazing that Anaconda distribution has MKL optimization for libraries like numpy, scipy etc.

I am wondering what if I use Miniconda instead, and install numpy via conda command, does it ship the same benefits of MLK optimization as what Anaconda does ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it ship the same benefits of MLK optimization as what Anaconda does.

These [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) installers contain the conda package manager and Python. Once Miniconda is installed, you can use the conda command to install any other packages and create environments, etc.

For example:

```
$ conda install numpy
...
$ conda create -n py3k anaconda python=3
...
```

> Note: If you already have Miniconda or Anaconda installed, and you just want to upgrade, you should not use the installer. Just use `conda update`.

For instance:

```
$ conda update conda
```

will update conda.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is exactly the same package as would come with the Anaconda installer.

Note that you can also install NumPy from the [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/) channel, if you wanted to use OpenBLAS instead of MKL.